# How many possible password combinations are there?

Tags: combinatorics

If the password needs to be 18 random characters, where

Exactly one character is an upper-case letter (A-Z)
Exactly one character is a number (0-9)
All other characters are lowercase letters (a-z)

How many possible passwords are there?

I was thinking its just 26+26+10 combinations for each letter and so 62^18 as the answer but there being exactly one of the uppercase letters and exactly one number being there are throwing me off

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. What have you tried?

Comment: I was thinking its just 26+26+10 combinations for each letter and so 62^18 as the answer but there being exactly one of the uppercase letters and exactly one number being there are throwing me off

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your thoughts? Problems without context or effort made to solve them tend to be closed

Comment: Sure. I have updated it

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the size of the your alphabet. Assuming the password all valid passwords have precisely 18 characters, there are exactly $3060 \cdot n^{17} = (18 \cdot n) \cdot (17 \cdot 10) \cdot n^{16}$ valid passwords.

Firstly, there are $18$ possible choices for the position of the uppercase letter and $n$ choices for this letter. This is where the $18n$ factor comes from. Secondly, there are $17$ possible choices for the position of the number and $10$ choices for such a number, so we multiply by a factor of $17 \cdot 10$. Finally, there are $16$ positions left, each of which with $n$ possible choices. Hence we multiply by $n^{16}$. If you assume $n = 26$ is the size of the standard English alphabet you get $ 3060 \cdot 26^{17}$ valid passwords.

Comment: Should it be $n^{16}$?

Comment: You're right! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since exactly one character is Uppercase and one character is a number, you don't have 62 possibilities for each character.

First, which one is Uppercase.
$${18 \choose 1}\times 26$$
Second the number
$${17 \choose 1}\times 10$$
Finally the rest could be any lowercase letter
$$26^{16}$$
Complete answer
$${18 \choose 1}\times 26\times {17\choose 1}\times 10 \times 26^{16}=18\times17\times10\times26^{17}$$